# cmake custom commands for remote operation

Tags: ssh, cmake

I am using trying to do a remote operation using cmake.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET MYTARGET POST_BUILD COMMAND ssh abcd@target "ps aux")
```

The above command works and I get a process list.

But the below command fails

```
add_custom_command(TARGET MYTARGET POST_BUILD COMMAND ssh abcd@target "ps aux | grep cron")
```

The error is /bin/sh: 1:  grep cron: not found
Any idea why?

Comment: Double quotes from `"ps aux | grep cron"` are stripped at CMake stage. If you want to remain them for shell, you need to escape them: `\"ps aux | grep cron\"`

Comment: The command ps aux | grep cron worked after escaping the quotes. But an other command doesnt work: ssh abcd@target \"pkill -f blah\".